# Mouse cursor does not show up on screen

Tags: mouse, cursor, mouse-pointer

the mouse works but there is no pointer on the screen how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

if its plug and play unplug and re-plug your USB mouse.

You can try

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Or try restarting lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

if this doesn't fix your issue, change lightdm to gdm:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Finally, this [article](https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-release/) describes a similar issue on xubuntu 16.04 that is fixed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> .